# How i can assign differents tags to various objects at runtime in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tags, runtime, firemonkey, pascal

How i can to assign differents tags to various objects (e.j: TCircle) of the same type at runtime?
Lets me explain that: I want to create various Circles at runtime and to assign to each one of them a different tag and then with on click event to show the Circle that i clicked.
This is a fragment of my code:

```
procedure 
TPhotoX.FormCreate(Sender: 
TObject);
var
 FilesN: String;
 S: TBitmap;
 Cir: TCircle;
begin
  FlowLayout1.DeleteChildren;
  GetFP:= TDirectory.GetFiles(GetPathIma, '*jpg', TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly);

for FilesN in GetFP do
VertScrollBox1.BeginUpdate;
Cir.TCircle.Create(Self);
Cir.Parent:= FlowLayOut1;  
Cir.Fill.Bitmap.WrapMode:=TWrapMode.TileOriginal;
Cir.Fill.Kind:= TBrushkind.Bitmap;
Cir.Height:= 85;
Cir.Width:= 85;

//...more circle's properties next including the Circle's Tag property that i ignore to implement
// Sorry i'm Delphi's Beginner but Delphi's power believer too!!! :-)

Cir.OnClick: CirClick;
try
S.TBitmap.Create;
FlowLayout1.AddObject(Cir);
S.LoadThumbnailsFromFile(FilesN, 150, 150);
Cir.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap:=S;
Cir.Repaint;
VertScrollBox1.EndUpdate;
finally
S.Free;
end;
end;

//in the code above, how i can to assign differents tags for each circle for referencing later with this handler:

procedure TPhotoX.CirClick(Sender:TObject);
begin
 case TCircle(Sender).Tag of
 1: //event to show the image 
 inside the circle
 2: // event to show another 
image inside the circle
 end;
end;
end;
```

I appreciate any kind of help... Thanks you

Comment: `S.TBitmap.Create;` must be `S := TBitmap.Create;` and it must be on the line *before* `try`.

Comment: Same with `Cir.TCircle.Create(Self)`, it needs to be `Cir := TCircle.Create(Self);` And you already know about the `Tag` property. What more are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Also, you need a `try..finally` block for `VertScrollBox1.(Begin|End)Update:`

Comment: The for loop won't work - needs a begin/end, or, as Remy says, a Try/finally

Comment: Because your `for` loop is of the form `for variable in collection` you don't have a natural integer index to assign the `tag` of each `Cir`. So, in `procedure TPhotoX.FormCreate()` declare a local variable `i: integer`, assign it the value 0 before the loop and increment it before you assign it to `Cir.Tag` for every new `Cir` you create.

Comment: @Dsm a `try/finally` alone won't fix the `for` loop issue. A `begin/end` is definitely needed. I missed that earlier.

Comment: thanks Remy. Wasn't quite sure about that.

Comment: Thank very much to every one of you...

Comment: @Dsm: A `try..finally..end` does create "blocks" like `begin..end`: `if x <> 0 then
  try
    p(x);
    q(x);
  finally
    r(x);
    s(x);
  end;` needs no `begin..end`. The problem here is that the required position of the `try..finally` isn't the right one to allow us to skip the for loop's `begin..end`. Just to mention one thing, the `BeginUpdate` should be *outside* (before) the `try`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, there are several mistakes in your code.  You are not creating the `TBitmap` and `TCircle` objects correctly.  You are not adequately protecting resources.  And your `for` loop lacks a required `begin/end` block to contain your loop logic.

And, to answer your question, since you are using a `for..in` loop, if you want to assign index-based `Tag` values then you need to use a separate variable to keep track of the current index as you iterate through the collection.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TPhotoX.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FilesN: String;
  S: TBitmap;
  Cir: TCircle;
  I: Integer;
begin
  FlowLayout1.DeleteChildren;
  GetFP := TDirectory.GetFiles(GetPathIma, '*jpg', TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly);
  if GetFP <> nil then Exit;

  VertScrollBox1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    I := 1;
    for FilesN in GetFP do
    begin
      Cir := TCircle.Create(Self);
      try
        Cir.Parent := FlowLayOut1;  
        Cir.Fill.Bitmap.WrapMode := TWrapMode.TileOriginal;
        Cir.Fill.Kind := TBrushkind.Bitmap;
        Cir.Height := 85;
        Cir.Width := 85;
        Cir.Tag := I; // <-- or whatever you need
        Inc(I);
        Cir.OnClick := CirClick;

        S := TBitmap.Create;
        try
          S.LoadThumbnailsFromFile(FilesN, 150, 150);
          Cir.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap := S;
        finally
          S.Free;
        end;

        FlowLayout1.AddObject(Cir);
      except
        Cir.Free;
        raise;
      end;

      //Cir.Repaint;
    end;
  finally
    VertScrollBox1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TPhotoX.CirClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case TCircle(Sender).Tag of
    1: // event to show the image inside the circle
    2: // event to show another image inside the circle
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Remy, i'm appreciate your answer and for the others too. My sincere respects for maintaining knowledge and legacy of Object Pascal Language. 